# Why do tasks with and without ExecutorService take the same amount of time?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, executorservice

I have the following project structure in spring boot using JDBC template and executor service. The application takes almost the same amount of time with thread and without thread. I expected the time reduction to be at least one third.

I read the following from this [link](https://egkatzioura.com/2017/10/25/spring-and-threads-transactions/) but I don know how to apply in my code:

*In order to be able to use transactions with our thread we need to understand how transactions work with spring. Transaction information in spring is stored in ThreadLocal variables. Therefore these variables are specific for an ongoing transaction on a single thread.*

**Is my long-running task in `SqlUtilities.executeSql(sqlName, values, dataSource)` cause the problem?**

**Does anyone know why? Any solution is welcome.**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationMain implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "mainExecutorService")
    public ExecutorService mainExecutorService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "mut")
    public Mut mut;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "apt")
    public Apt apt;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        try {
            // First thread
            mainExecutorService.submit(() -> {
                mut.initialise("2019", "10", "31");
                apt.sum();
            }, true);

            // Second thread
            mainExecutorService.submit(() -> {
                apt.initialise("2019", "10", "31");
                mut.sum();
            }, true);
            mainExecutorService.shutdown();

            if (mainExecutorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                System.out.println("done");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mainExecutorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

**configuration**

```
@Configuration
class ExecutorservicConfig {
    @Bean("mainExecutorService")
    public ExecutorService mainExecutorService() {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    }

    @Bean(name = "apt")
    public Apt createApt(){
        return new Apt();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mut")
    public Mut createMut(){
        return new Mut();
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
    interface Som {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    void initialize (String year, String month, String day);
    void sum();
    void deleteInsertUpdate();
    void execute();
    void print();
}
```

**First class considers being executed in the first thread**

```
    class Mut implements Som {
    private String year, month, day ;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "jdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private long staringProcessingTime;

    @Override
    public void initialize (String year, String month, String day) {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Override
    public void sum() {
        staringProcessingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Started first thread. starting time is:".concat(String.valueOf(staringProcessingTime)));
        deleteInsertUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteInsertUpdate() {
        String queryDelete = "";
        String queryInsert = "";
        String queryUpdate = "";

        try {
            service.submit(() -> jdbcTemplate.update(queryDelete));
            service.submit(() -> jdbcTemplate.update(queryInsert));
            service.submit(() -> jdbcTemplate.update(queryUpdate));
            service.shutdown();
            if (service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                execute();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            service.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // long running task here ....
        if( SqlUtilities.executeSql(sqlName, values, dataSource) )
            print();
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        long endProcessingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Ended first thread. total time in millisecond:".concat(String.valueOf(endProcessingTime - staringProcessingTime)));
    }

}
```

**Second class considers being executed in the second thread.**

```
class Apt implements Som {
    private String year, month, day ;
    private long staringProcessingTime;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "jdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void initialize (String year, String month, String day) {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Override
    public void sum() {
        staringProcessingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Started Second thread. starting time is:".concat(String.valueOf(staringProcessingTime)));
        deleteInsertUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteInsertUpdate() {
        String queryDelete = "";
        String queryInsert = "";
        String queryUpdate = "";

        try {
            service.submit(() -> jdbcTemplate.update(queryDelete));
            service.submit(() -> jdbcTemplate.update(queryInsert));
            service.submit(() -> jdbcTemplate.update(queryUpdate));
            service.shutdown();
            if (service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                execute();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            service.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // long running task here ....
        if( SqlUtilities.executeSql(sqlName, values, dataSource) )
            print();
    }

    @Override
    public void print() {
        long endProcessingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Ended second thread. total time in millisecond:".concat(String.valueOf(endProcessingTime - staringProcessingTime)));
    }

}
```

**Utilities class**

```
class SqlUtilities {

public static boolean executeSql(String sqlName, Map<String,String> values, DataSource dataSource){
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    boolean executed = false;
    try{
        Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:sql/*.sql");

        for(Resource resource: resources)
        {
            if(sqlName.equals(resource.getFilename()))
            {
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile(resource.getFilename(), ".sql");
                Path tempPath = Paths.get(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
                try (InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
                    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, tempFile);

                    String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(tempPath));
                    String newContents = StringSubstitutor.replace(contents, values);

                    Files.write(tempPath, Collections.singleton(newContents), StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);

                    Resource tempResource = new FileUrlResource(tempPath.toString());
                    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(tempResource);
                    databasePopulator.execute(dataSource);
                } finally {
                    executed = Files.deleteIfExists(tempPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());;
    }

    return executed;
}
```

Comment: This code won't run. `@Autowired` doesn't work on `static` fields. They do the same amount of work, why should one be faster then the other?

Comment: When in doubt, use profiler to see where your program is spending most of time.

Comment: You are right about @Autowired,  it is just for demonstration will be corrected thanks.
this project was initially without thread and the amount of time takes is almost the same as when I use thread. This is why I am curious about it to know why this happens.

Comment: @rkosegi 
I have never used a profiler, can you please suggest some good profiler?

Comment: Do the tasks actually run in different threads? Try logging. Do the tasks directly or indirectly involve synchronization that might cause them to run sequentially?

Comment: Yes, it runs in a different thread and not any synchronization involved.